# I need to know how I can set up a spreadsheet with an error checking formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm wanting to set up a spreadsheet with one of the columns listing microchip numbers.   The microchip numbers always start with a "9" and the numbers always contain a total of 15 digits.
Basically the sheet will only need 2 columns being 1 for the chip number and one for the animal's name.
The reason for this "safeguard" is to alert anyone doing data entry that they have either mis-typed a number or the source of the number that they have entered, is incorrect.
I have included a small sample of the spreadsheet.
If anyone is able to help it would be appreciated and I will also need some advice on how to utilise the formula

[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is called data validation. See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249. Select one cell, and use that cell in your formula. EG: `=AND(LENGTH(B4)=15;B4="123456789012345")` After it works, copy that cell to any other cell you want this to work with.

Comment: This? https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.htm

Comment: @Paul Lewis .. anything works so far?